# Find a subgroup of rationals under addition that contains Integers but is different from both Integers and Rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find a group that is smaller than the set of all rationals, but bigger than than the set of integers but I don't know how to begin.

Comment: Take the half integers.

Comment: What if I challenge you to find such a group that contains $1/2$?

Comment: so, the set of all integers along with half integers? or their thirds? Is that all the questions is asking? @TedShifrin

Comment: Something that's a group, bigger than $\Bbb Z$ and smaller than all of $\Bbb Q$.